# how to show content depending on domain/subdomain

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a little blog where only some specific content of blog should show up depending on domain/subdomain.

lets say, the main blog is at `www.mainblogsite.com`. here I want to show all blog entries.

But lets say, there is also a subdomain of main blog, called `www.fr.mainblogsite.com` where only blog entries in french should show up.

I am writing the blog in Django.

my first thoughts on database modelling were like this:

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  lang = models.CharField(max_length="2")
```

I just get the domain with `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` and depending on domain name, i will filter blog entries by language like

```
#for fr.mainblogsite.com
BlogEntry.objects.filter(lang='fr')
```

which gives me only french blog entries for `fr.mainblogsite.com`

my question is: does this database architecture make sense? I dont know much about how domains and subdomains work,.. how and where could it be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have a look at the [`django.contrib.sites`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) models, which are there for precisely the problem you are trying to solve - have multiple subdomain and domain represented by the content.

Quoting the example mentioned there:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    # ...
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
```

Answer (score 1):

From a DB design standpoint you should move the `lang` field to an own model and reference it from the BlogEntry.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    lang = models.CharField(max_length="2")

class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    lang = manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Language')
```

That way you can change the actual name of the language by updating a single record and not multiple. However, if you are sure that this will never you can also stick with your approach.

Comment: did you mean ``lang = models.ForeignKey(Language)``?